# Fetch key values directly from a custom hash format

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash as shown below:

```
hash_ex = {:"p, q," => "1, 2,"}
```

And `hash_ex[:p]` returns `nil`:

```
hash_ex[:p]
# => nil
```

Instead, it should be `1`. How would I be able to get this key value?

Answer (score 2):

There is no defined key `:p` in `hash_ex`. Therefore `nil` is expected result.

```
hash_ex = {:"p, q,"=>"1, 2,"}
hash_ex.keys
# => [:"p, q,"]

hash_ex[:"p, q,"]
# => "1, 2,"
```

The above example shows that you have declared `"p, q,"` as a key. Also `"p, q,"` here is being treated as a Symbol and not a String. Therefore `hash_ex["p, q,"]` will also return `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

> But `hash_ex[:p]` returns `nil` instead it should be `1`

Ruby is not an AI, it can't figure out how to parse your "custom Hash format".

> How I would be able to get this key value?

Well, you have to convert your format into a structure that Ruby understands:

```
key_string = "p, q,"
value_string = "1, 2,"

keys = key_string.split(/,\s*/).map(&:to_sym)   #=> [:p, :q]
values = value_string.split(/,\s*/).map(&:to_i) #=> [1, 2]

hash_ex = keys.zip(values).to_h
hash_ex[:p] #=> 1
```